# <input /> does not work inside <details /> element

Tags: reactjs, input

I recently came up with a really frustrating - weird issue. I tried to put a `<input />` element inside a `<details/>` one, but anything I do does not seem to work. If I move the line with the `<input />` one line above, everything works great as expected but inside of the `<details />` element, nothing seems to function.

Here is a snipper of the related code:

```
<div className="select__container" ref={divRef} data-testid="select-container">
        <details
          ref={isMobile ? undefined : modalRef}
          className={classNames}
          open={isOpen}
          onToggle={e => handleToggle(e)}
          onKeyDown={e => handleKeyDown(e)}
          data-testid="select"
          {...rest}
        >
          <input type="text" value={inputVal} onChange={e => setInputVal(e.target.value)} />
          {children}
       </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<div className="select__container" ref={divRef} data-testid="select-container">
        <details
          ref={isMobile ? undefined : modalRef}
          className={classNames}
          open={isOpen}
          onToggle={e => handleToggle(e)}
          onKeyDown={e => handleKeyDown(e)}
          data-testid="select"
          {...rest}
        >

          <div> 
          <input type="text" value={inputVal} onChange={e => setInputVal(e.target.value)} />

          {children} 
         </div>
       </details>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it, but the issue was coming from the `handleKeyDown()` method, as I fixed it. You can see my answer at this if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a stupidity of mine, but I believe that all other developers, should be able to see the "correct" answer to this issue, as they may struggle themselves too with something else similar. Well when I was typing in the `<input />` element, the `<details />` element was focused.

So, in combination with the fact that I had defined an `onKeyDown()` handler, which was preventing by default the default behaviour with `e.preventDefault()`, I used a `switch()` to differentiate between each key - case, and guess what of course that was for only some of specific keys, not for all the keys on the keyboard. In summary, I checked if the condition `e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement` in the `handleKeyDown()` method, and if yes, then do not prevent the default behaviour.

```
const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  [...]
```